# Heading tag in css creates new line

Tags: html, css, tags

I'm trying to make some input boxes with text infront of it, but each time i style the text in CSS, the styling forces my input box "to a new line". In the image the first 2 text parts is unstyled, and the next 4 is. I want my styled texts not to create a new line.

Image: http://puu.sh/8kPKl.png

**The html part:**

```
<h0>Fulde navn:</h5> <input type="text" name="name"><br>
<h0>E-mail:</h5> <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<h5>Telefon nr:</h5> <input type="text" name="tlf"><br>
<h5>Antal personer:</h5> <input type="text" name="pers"><br>
<h5>Flytype:</h5> <input type="text" name="type"><br>
<h5>Betalingsform:</h5> <input type="text" name="betal"><br>
```

**And the CSS part:**

```
#four h5 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heading elements are block level elements by default. Try adding `display:inline`

```
#four h5 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline;
}
```

`inline-block` works as well.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5SEre/

Answer (score 0):

Three things here:

### 1. Your first two headings are `<h0>`'s

Make them `<h5>`'s

### 2. That extra space below the `<h5>`'s is a margin:

```
#four h5{
    margin: 0;
}
```

### 3. Block Elements

As pointed out by [**@DrydenLong**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1636876/dryden-long) in [**his answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23256761/heading-tag-in-css-creates-new-line/23256803#23256803), headings are block elements, and so they automatically render on their own line. You can fix this by setting them to be inline or inline-block elements:

```
#four h5{
    display: inline;
    //or
    display: inline-block;
}
```